# Short story where the universe is a simulation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I recall reading a short story some time ago (years?) of which I can no longer recall the author or story name.

The setting was on Earth, I cannot recall the time period.  The premise was that there was a group of scientists trying to create a simulation of the universe.

The story begins with one of the scientists making a breakthrough and calling the other members of the team into the lab. He shows them the simulation he is running. He zooms the simulation in to their lab. The simulation shows the people currently in the room on the screen exactly how they are in the "real" world.  The breakthrough-scientist then goes a step further - he has the simulation put some actual object in the room with the scientists (a camera? a box? I don't recall exactly what).  As he executes this, the object that he puts in the simulation appears in the "real" world alongside them, showing that the scientists in fact are part of the simulation themselves.

Anyone know what story this could be and who wrote it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

And of course, after spending hours searching prior to posting, I find the story shortly after!

["I don't know, Timmy, being God is a big responsibility" by Sam Hughes](https://qntm.org/responsibility).

> She tapped a button just as a clock on the wall lined up with a clock inside the control room on the screen. And panned down. And there they were.
>
> Tim waved at the camera while still looking at the screen. Then he looked up at where the camera should have been. There was just blank wall. "I don't see anything looking at us. That's freaky as hell."

....

> "Tim, look behind you," said Diane, pressing a final key and activating the very brief interference program she had just written, just as the Diane on the screen pressed the same key, and the Diane on Diane-on-the-screen's screen pressed her key and so on, forever.
>
> Tim looked backwards and nearly jumped out of his skin. There was a foot-wide, completely opaque black sphere up near the ceiling, partially obscuring the clock. It was absolutely inert. It seemed like a hole in space.
>
> Diane smiled wryly while Tim clutched his hair with one hand. "We're constructs in a computer," he said, miserably.

Comment: Very nice story ;) Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Thanks for posting a link to it. Been years since I read it too and it popped into my head today.